# moment.js formatting date wrong

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, format, momentjs

I'm trying to get upcoming date using `moment.js`. The date is obtained, but it's formatted wrongly. According to docs, `format('l')` formats the date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and `format('L')` formats date in `mm/dd/yyyy`. but I'm getting the same output for both. Here is my code.

```js
let next = moment().add(30, 'days').format('l'); // Output 10/16/2019
let next = moment().add(30, 'days').format('L'); // Output 10/16/2019
let next = moment().add(30, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY'); // Works fine
```

I tried i with `moment.js v2.24.0` what's wrong in here? am I missing something or doing it wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to docs, `format('l')` formats the date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format and `format('L')` formats date in `mm/dd/yyyy`.

No, that isn't what [the documentation says](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

> **Localized formats**
>
> Because preferred formatting differs based on locale, there are a few tokens that can be used to format a moment based on its locale.
>
> There are upper and lower case variations on the same formats. The lowercase version is intended to be the shortened version of its uppercase counterpart.
>
> ```
> Month numeral, day of month, year:   L    09/04/1986
>                                      l    9/4/1986
> ```

There's nothing there saying `L` will use one field order and `l` another.

It's using your current Moment locale to format the date. See the [i18n section](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) for how to set locales, globally or per instance.

Comment: So, `DD/MM/YYYY` will not work using shortcode `l` or `L`? I have to `.format('DD/MM/YYYY')`?

Comment: @KiranManiya - Or set your locale correctly, as I said at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs

moment().format('L');    // 09/16/2019
moment().format('l');    // 9/16/2019

https://momentjs.com/